# Hibernate not updating persistent object

Tags: hibernate

I have following code:

```
Criteria criteria = currentSession.createCriteria(Activity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("activityId", activityId));

List<Activity> existingActivities = criteria.list();

if(existingActivities.size() == 0){
    System.out.println("No Activity exist for activity id: "+activityId);
    continue;
}

    Activity activity = existingActivities.get(0);

    User assignTo = users.get(UNKNOWN);

    activity.setUser(assignTo);
    currentSession.flush();
```

I was expecting hibernate will shoot an update statement and will save my persistent object activity with new user. But It did not work. I am using Hibernate with Spring. Method is marked as @Transactional. I thought I didn't have to put session.flush(). So I tried with that as well. It didn't work. Please guide me if I am doing something wrong here.

I have also tried explicit call to update. I can see update statement in the SQL logs but Its not updating my database.

Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: Is the method that is marked as transactional being called from the same class? If so Spring doesn't support that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072749/hibernate-spring-annotation-sessions-not-being-closed-flushed

Comment: No its called from different class. Not sure what is the problem. I tried to do session.evict() and then tried to update the object. I can see update query in sql logs but its not updating the database. One more thing the users from where I am fetching user is also fetched from database. I am not sure if that is making any difference.

Comment: Just call session.save()/saveOrUpdate() on your Activity object. like that: currentSession.saveOrUpdate(activity). If it doesn't work, maybe your cascade options are wrong. If so, please post your classes so we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had to change my Cascade options. It worked after that.